# Accesing Cosmos data with Hive from Javascript

Tags: javascript, fiware

I'm triying to access data stored in Cosmos by using javascript to create a web interface. I know there's a java code available to make query's with Hive. That code is shown below:

```
    private Connection getConnection(
      String ip, String port, String user, String password) {
   try {
      // dynamically load the Hive JDBC driver
      Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      return null;
   } // try catch

   try {
      // return a connection based on the Hive JDBC driver, default DB
      return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://" + ip + ":" +
         port + "/default?user=" + user + "&password=" + password);
   } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      return null;
   } // try catch
} // getConnection


    private void doQuery() {
   try {
      // from here on, everything is SQL!
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("select column1,column2," +
         "otherColumns from mytable where column1='whatever' and " +
         "columns2 like '%whatever%'");

      // iterate on the result
      while (res.next()) {
         String column1 = res.getString(1);
         Integer column2 = res.getInteger(2);
         // whatever you want to do with this row, here
      } // while

      // close everything
      res.close(); stmt.close(); con.close();
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
      System.exit(0);
   } // try catch
} // doQuery
```

I need to know how to implement that code in javascript, I know it's possible but I don't know how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Hive 0.13, a JavaScript client may use the [Thrift library](https://thrift.apache.org/) in order to send Thrift RPC messages on top of Http. The problem is the current version of Hive in FIWARE LAB is 0.9, and thus it must be updated. We are currently [working on it](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/issues/25), because this is a requiremente for a [Wirecloud-based Hive client](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/29) as well. Stay tuned!

Comment: So... what's the best way to access data stored in Cosmos right now?

Comment: Regarding data querying (which can be considered as basic analysis) there is no other way than writting a Hive client as the one you are trying (continues...)

Comment: (...) The keypoint here is that you must use a different language than Javascript for Hive querying due to such a language needs to use Thrift, which is not currently supported by our Hive server (continues...)

Comment: (...)  Instead of that, Java or Python may be used in the backend for Hive querying purposes, and this backend may be invoked by your Javascript frontend. We have published an application following such an architecture [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-connectors/tree/develop/resources/plague-tracker). There, you will see jQuery is used for invoking the Java-based backend from the Javascript-based frontend.

Comment: Hello. The link in the above comment is broken. Can you please paste an updated link as that would be very helpful.

Comment: You are right, it was moved. Working one: https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-livedemoapp/tree/master/plague-tracker