# Read data from Cosmos using Wirecloud

Tags: fiware-wirecloud, cosmos

I am working in a project of SmartAgrifood and I have to use Fispace platform. This platform supports widgets. Currently I store data in Cosmos, and I need read  this data from Cosmos using Wirecloud. Is there any example for this?

Comment: You could be interested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366059/accesing-cosmos-data-with-hive-from-javascript